# Multiple language sitemap gives validation error "No matching global element declaration available"

Tags: xml, validation, sitemap, multilingual

I have been trying to follow [Google's recommendation for multi-lingual sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en). However when I try this on my site I get the error:

> Error 1845: Element '`{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}link`': No matching global element declaration available, but demanded by the strict wildcard.

Even when I paste Google's example into the sitemap validator I get the same error. Is there something I am missing here?

Here is Google's example I've been pasting into the validator:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/english/</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="de"
                 href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/"
                 />
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="de-ch"
                 href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/"
                 />
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://www.example.com/english/"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/deutsch/</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://www.example.com/english/"
                 />
     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="de-ch"
                 href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/"
                 />
     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="de"
                 href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/</loc>
     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="de"
                 href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/"
                 />
     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://www.example.com/english/"
                 />
<xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="de-ch"
                 href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/"
                 />
  </url>

</urlset>
```

Comment: Which validator do you use?

Comment: http://tools.seochat.com/tools/site-validator/

Answer (score 4):

It seems the validator you use, http://tools.seochat.com/tools/site-validator/, doesn’t support [additional namespaces](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#extending) (like `xhtml` in your example).

Comment: so what online resource is better for validation? Because i have same problems, and not sure that my sitemap is valid. Thanks!

Comment: @LINKeRxUA: You could ask on [softwarerecs.se] (recommendations are off-topic here on Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 4):

Add a `/` at the end of your xhtml namespace definition like this:

`<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/">`

Comment: This is not correct. XML **namespace names** are compared "[as strings](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NSNameComparison)", so appending a slash would describe a different namespace. A namespace name does NOT have to be "[usable for retrieval of a schema](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl)". The namespace name for XHTML is "[http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml](https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/)"

Comment: This is not passing any sitemap validators I have found, do you have proof this works?